# Transfer a string to a new column using python pattern

Tags: python, regex, pandas

I'm trying to extract a text from a column so I can transfer this text to another column using a python pattern, but I lose some results at the same time I need to hold the remaining strings in the current column.

**My code is:**

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'col': ['abcd (30-10) hijk', 'hijk (200-100) abcd', 'abcd (100 FS) hijk', 'hijk (100+) abcd', 'abcd (1000-2000) hijk' ]
})

pattern = "(abcd\d*)\s(\(.*\))"

df['remainingcol'] = df['col'].str.extract(pattern)[0]
df['newcol'] = df['col'].str.extract(pattern)[1]

print(df)
```

**Output is:**

```
                col            remainingcol      newcol
0       abcd (30-10) hijk      abcd              (30-10)
1       hijk (200-100) abcd    hijk             (200-100)
2       abcd (100 FS) hijk     abcd             (100 FS)
3       hijk (100+) abcd       hijk              (100+)
4       abcd (1000-2000) hijk  abcd            (1000-2000)
```

**Output should be**

```
                col            remainingcol      newcol
0       abcd (30-10) hijk      abcd hijk        (30-10)
1       hijk (200-100) abcd    hijk abcd       (200-100)
2       abcd (100 FS) hijk     abcd hijk        (100 FS)
3       hijk (100+) abcd       hijk abcd        (100+)
4       abcd (1000-2000) hijk  abcd hijk       (1000-2000)
```

**I tried Tim's solution but I get this output, there's an issue with newcol:**

```
              col                        remainingcol      newcol
0     abcd (30-10) abcd                     abcd abcd        
1  abcd (200-100) abcd                     abcd abcd         
2    abcd (100 FS) abcd                    abcd abcd         
3      abcd (100+) abcd                    abcd abcd         
4  abcd (1000-2000) ZZZ                     abcd ZZZ
```

[image: Last output]

Answer (score 3):

For the remaining column I would use `str.replace` and a a regex replacement:

```py
df['remainingcol'] = df['col'].str.replace('\s+\(.*?\)\s+', ' ')
```

For the new column, I would use `str.replace` with a capture group:

```
df['newcol'] = df['col'].str.replace('.*(\(.*?\)).*', '\1')
```

Comment: Hi Tim I get this char in newcol